# Consul Check HTTPS self signed

Tags: consul

I use Consul to register a web application. The web app use Java Consul client to register with check. I am able to activate TLS and encryption using a self signed CA to encrypt exchanges between consul agents and between my webapp and consul agent. But I am not able to make checks onto a HTTPS with self signed CA signed certificate.

My web application is secured and listens only on HTTPS with a self signed certificate. When I register a session with consul and provide a https://... URL for check, I am rejected:

com.orbitz.consul.ConsulException: Consul request failed with status [500]: rpc error: rpc error: Check 'service:a4cHealthCheck:172.17.0.3' is in critical state

In consul agent logs, I can see:

```
2016/07/23 08:24:45 [WARN] agent: http request failed 'https://172.17.0.3:8443/rest/latest/health/check': Get https://172.17.0.3:8443/rest/latest/health/check: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

It seems that the consul agent don't accept self signed certificates for checks. How can I disable SSL verify only for checks or provide a truster for checks ?

Answer (score 2):

Golang crypto lib have a set paths he looks for trustworthy authorities. This varies by OS, but for Linux systems you can check the following link.

https://golang.org/src/crypto/x509/root_linux.go

So, you can have your issue solved by installing your CA into the system defaults.

For how to install a root certificate, see

https://superuser.com/questions/437330/how-do-you-add-a-certificate-authority-ca-to-ubuntu

or for others OS

http://kb.kerio.com/product/kerio-connect/server-configuration/ssl-certificates/adding-trusted-root-certificates-to-the-server-1605.html

Comment: holy cow, took me hours before i find your post! thanks a lot!

Comment: I did not managed to make it work for MacOS with the link you provide. Any idea of another solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can disabled the HTTPS checks with the property `tls_skip_verify`. It is described in the section HTTP of the [Consul checks documentation](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/checks.html).
If you use a JSON file to configure your agent, here is an example of configuration.

```
{
  "services": [
    {
      "id": "instance-1",
      "name": "ManagementService",
      "address": "localhost",
      "port": 11080,
      "checks": [
        {
          "id": "api",
          "name": "HTTP API",
          "http": "https://localhost:11081/service/monitoring/ping",
          "tls_skip_verify": true,
          "interval": "5s",
          "timeout": "1s"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: hi @nicolas: I am windows platform to run the consul. I have tried the similar config which u posted. But the health check never registered. Any idea? My whole config is here:   {
  "service": {
    "id":"somename",
 "name":"nameofthissevice",
    "service": "myservice",
    "address": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 62133,
    "enableTagOverride": false,
 "check": {
"id": "somename",
"name": "nameofthissevice",
"http": "http://127.0.0.1:62133/Service1.svc/MyService/PingMe",
"tls_skip_verify": false,
"method": "GET",
"interval": "10s",
"timeout": "1s"
}
  }
}

Comment: What version of consul are you using ?

Comment: Hi @nicolas, Tried on 0.9.0 on windows platform.

Comment: https is missing in your check definition `{ "service": { "id":"somename", "name":"nameofthissevice", "service": "myservice", "address": "127.0.0.1", "port": 62133, "enableTagOverride": false, "check": { "id": "somename", "name": "nameofthissevice", "http": "https://127.0.0.1:62133/Service1.svc/MyService/PingMe";, "tls_skip_verify": false, "method": "GET", "interval": "10s", "timeout": "1s" } } }`

Comment: Hi @nicolas, Still no luck. Any other idea/suggestion on this one? I also created a seperate thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45576409/unable-to-create-http-health-check-from-config-file-consul with more. Could u help me out. Thx.

Comment: I just noticed you have use the flag to `false`. Use `"tls_skip_verify": true` instead.

Comment: Hi @nicolas, Tried but still no luck. I have updated my question with the logs. Since it is big I cannot paste here.  Here is my config.

{
 "service": {
  "id": "somename",
  "name": "nameofthissevice",
  "service": "myservice",
  "address": "127.0.0.1",
  "port": 62133,
  "enableTagOverride": false,
  "check": {
   "id": "somename11",
   "name": "nameofthissevice",
   "http": "http://localhost:62133/Service1.svc/MyService/PingMe",
   "tls_skip_verify": true,
   "method": "GET",
   "interval": "10s",
   "timeout": "30s"   
  }
 }
}

Any other ideas? Thx in advance.

Comment: Hi @nicolas: Ah no. Tried https,http,localhost. Still in consul UI, it is not showing my health check. Any issue with the version or because of I am using consul for windows or any other idea? I can see only  "2017/08/11 09:17:18 [DEBUG] agent: restored service definition "somename" from "services\\ServiceRegister.json"" this line in my command prompt. Thx in advance.