# Consul https support for spring boot application

Tags: ssl, spring-boot, spring-security, https, consul

I have a spring boot application that runs on https. Consul is unable to do the health check due to the application is https. When i change it to http, it works.

Any solution for this?

thanks

Comment: i checked this link but i couldn't get any clue from it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38539924/consul-check-https-self-signed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out below Spring boot configuration. Notice the scheme property

[image: Spring boot configuration]

Secondly add your SSL certificate under trusted root certificates

[image]